# Python: Loop through tuple and insert into Data Frame for each value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

Trying to loop through the tuple that is currently a column in my data frame. For the first ID I want to select the first item in the group tuple then for the second ID select the second variable in the tuple. For the remaining ID's in the same group I would like to cycle back through the tuple.

If the group changes I would like to repeat the process with the new group. I'm also fine with splitting it into a new data frame and then union the results back in later.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'Group':["('Cat','Dog')",
                             "('Cat','Dog')",
                             "('Cat','Dog')",
                             "('Cat','Dog')",
                             "('Bird','Dog')",
                             "('Bird','Dog')",                             
                            ]
                  })
```

| ID | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ('Cat', 'Dog') |
| 2 | ('Cat', 'Dog') |
| 3 | ('Cat', 'Dog') |
| 4 | ('Cat', 'Dog') |
| 5 | ('Bird', 'Dog') |
| 6 | ('Bird', 'Dog') |

| ID | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat |
| 2 | Dog |
| 3 | Cat |
| 4 | Dog |
| 5 | Bird |
| 6 | Dog |

Comment: What about the 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc. IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a column of tuples:

```
df['Group'] = (df.groupby(df['ID'].sub(1).mod(2))['Group']
                 .transform(lambda s: s.str[s.name])
               )
```

If you have strings:

```
from ast import literal_eval
df['Group'] = (df['Group'].apply(literal_eval)
               .groupby(df['ID'].sub(1).mod(2))
               .transform(lambda s: s.str[s.name])
              )
```

Output:

```
   ID Group
0   1   Cat
1   2   Dog
2   3   Cat
3   4   Dog
4   5  Bird
5   6   Dog
```

Comment: Thanks @Ian, but I had updated in the meantime to first use `sub(1)` ;)

Comment: I will rollback.

Comment: @Ian I prefer the sub to keep the mod an integer, which makes it easier to generalize to 3/4/… elements :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'Group': ["('Cat','Dog')",
                             "('Cat','Dog')",
                             "('Cat','Dog')",
                             "('Cat','Dog')",
                             "('Bird','Dog')",
                             "('Bird','Dog')",
                             ]
                   })

# Extract the tuple from the 'Group' column and convert it to a tuple
df['Group'] = df['Group'].apply(eval)
df['Group_Length'] = df['Group'].apply(len)

# Calculate the index of the item to be selected based on the 'ID'
df['Selected_Index'] = (df['ID'] - 1) % df['Group_Length']

# Select the item from the tuple based on the calculated index
df['Selected_Item'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: row['Group'][row['Selected_Index']], axis=1)

# Drop the intermediate columns
df = df.drop(['Group', 'Group_Length', 'Selected_Index'], axis=1)
```

The Output will be:

[image: Output]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with more details. Please, consider adding some explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post. See How to Answer for some hints.  See [answer] for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Create a copy of the original dataframe and assign it to temp_df
temp_df = df.copy()

# Explode the 'Group' column in the temp_df dataframe
temp_df = temp_df.explode('Group').reset_index(drop=True)

# Strip the brackets and split the values in the 'Group' column
temp_df['Group'] = temp_df['Group'].str.strip("()").str.split(",")

# Explode the 'Group' column again to create one row per value
temp_df = temp_df.explode('Group').reset_index(drop=True)

# Strip the single quotes from the values in the 'Group' column
temp_df['Group'] = temp_df['Group'].str.strip("'")

# Print the modified temp_df dataframe
print(temp_df)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with more details. Please, consider adding some explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post. See [answer] for some hints.